# Share video on facebook with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I Need to share a video on facebook, and have fileURL of this video, but to share I need the asset URL of this video. How can I get the asset URL from a local video without using UIImagePickerViewController?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook SDK requires asset URL, so you have to pass your video file to asset library and get the new url from it. The complete code look like:

```
NSURL *_videoURL = [URL to local video file];
//initilize the asset library object and define the completion block
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock videoWriteCompletionBlock =
^(NSURL *newURL, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
    } else {
        NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library %@", newURL.absoluteString);
        //share to facebook when we have new asset URL
        FBSDKShareVideo *shareVideo = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc]init];
        shareVideo.videoURL = newURL;
        FBSDKShareVideoContent *shareContent = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
        shareContent.video = shareVideo;
        [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:shareContent delegate:nil];
    }
};

//write video file and fire up facebook sharing diaglog when complete
if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:_videoURL])
{
    [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:_videoURL
                                completionBlock:videoWriteCompletionBlock];
}
```

**UPDATED (for iOS SDK 9.0+):**

```
 NSURL *_videoURL = [URL to local video file];
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
    PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest= [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL:_videoURL];
    _videoPlaceHolder= [changeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset];

} completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog( @"Error writing image with metadata to Photo Library: %@", error );
    } else {
        NSLog( @"Wrote image with metadata to Photo Library %@", [_videoPlaceHolder localIdentifier]);
        //example for localidentifier:2BC8A8A8-E974-42D9-AD0F-2F463B353914/L0/001
        NSArray *id=[_videoPlaceHolder.localIdentifier componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *path= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=%@&ext=MOV",id[0]];
        _videoAssetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //share to facebook
            FBSDKShareVideo *shareVideo = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc]init];
            shareVideo.videoURL = _videoAssetURL;
            FBSDKShareVideoContent *shareContent = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
            shareContent.video = shareVideo;
            [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:shareContent delegate:nil];
        });
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! But `ALAssetsLibrary` is already deprecated, I need this code working without `ALAssetsLibrary`, you know?!

Comment: Check my update for using `PHPhotoLibrary` as replacement of `ALAssetsLibrary` from iOS SDK 9.0, just make sure the extension of your video file correct (MOV by default)

Answer (score 0):

```
import FacebookShare

let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent)
shareDialog.mode = .Native
shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true
shareDialog.completion = { result in 
    // Handle share results
}

try shareDialog.show()
```

Refer Facebook Developer API for More Detail

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/share-dialog

Comment: Your exemple just show how to open the dialog, I know how to open it. My question is how to get the asset URL form a local video without using `UIImagePickerViewController`.